# How to mutate multiple variables of a tibble to the same value in R at nce

Tags: r, across

I want to mutate the values of columns 2 to 4 t `NA`. I tried to use `mutate across` without success.

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(year = 2020, a = 1, b = 2, c = 3)


df %>% mutate(across(c(2:4), is.na))
#> # A tibble: 1 x 4
#>    year a     b     c    
#>   <dbl> <lgl> <lgl> <lgl>
#> 1  2020 FALSE FALSE FALSE

# But this gives an error because NA is not a function
# df %>% mutate(across(c(2:4), NA))
Created on 2021-10-30 by the reprex package (v2.0.1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an anonymous function or `~`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% mutate(across(c(2:4), ~NA))

#   year a     b     c    
#  <dbl> <lgl> <lgl> <lgl>
#1  2020 NA    NA    NA
```

In base R, you can do -

```
df[2:4] <- NA
```

Answer (score 1):

If we need the class to be the same as the input for each of the columns, multiply (`*`) with `NA` or else `NA` by default is `NA_logical_` which may have clash later when we try to change values in those columns

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    mutate(across(2:4, `*`, NA))
# A tibble: 1 × 4
   year     a     b     c
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1  2020    NA    NA    NA
```